# Create QML object from C++ with specified properties

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

Dynamically instantiating a QML object from C++ is [well documented](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#loading-qml-objects-from-c), but what I can't find is how to instantiate it with pre-specified values for it's properties.

For example, I am creating a slightly modified `SplitView` from C++ like this:

```
QQmlEngine* engine = QtQml::qmlEngine( this );
QQmlComponent splitComp( engine, QUrl( "qrc:/qml/Sy_splitView.qml" ) );
QObject* splitter = splitComp.create();

splitter->setProperty( "orientation", QVariant::fromValue( orientation ) );
```

The problem I have is that specifying the `orientation` of the `SplitView` *after* it is instantiated causes it's internal layout to break.  So, is there a way of creating the `SplitView` with the `orientation` already specified?

Alternatively I can create both a horizontal and vertical version of `SplitView` in separate files and instantiate the appropriate one at runtime - but this is less elegant.

**Update**

I found `QQmlComponent::beginCreate(QQmlContext* publicContext)`:

```
QQmlEngine* engine = QtQml::qmlEngine( this );
QQmlComponent splitComp( engine, QUrl( "qrc:/qml/Sy_splitView.qml" ) );
QObject* splitter = splitComp.beginCreate( engine->contextForObject( this ) );

splitter->setProperty( "orientation", QVariant::fromValue( orientation ) );
splitter->setParent( parent() );
splitter->setProperty( "parent", QVariant::fromValue( parent() ) );
splitComp.completeCreate();
```

But it had no effect surprisingly.

Comment: I bet the thing is in how you attempt to assign the enum via QVariant (enums are somewhat buggy in QML). I'd try to first register a simple QObject based type and a custom enum and check if the whole thing works at all. [also note, that you apparently attempt to set parent twice, but that's minor]

Comment: I didn't know that about enums, so thanks I'll try it.  And I'm not setting the parent twice, I set the `QObject` parent first, and then QML visual parent second (if I could set the `QObject` parent via QML, I wouldn't have bothered with C++ at all for this).

Comment: Right, indeed; instead of setting the QObject parent though, you could set memory ownership (or however it is called) to QmlOwnership, I believe (so that the freshly created object will be garbage-colleced / ref-counted by the QML runtime as necessary). Btw, is it that you specifically need to set the QObject parent for some reasons other than memory management?

Comment: It is for memory management.  Each `SplitView` contains two custom OSG viewports, each of which in turn can be split ad infinitum (like Qt Creator's text editor panes), forming a tree.  So when I delete a particular splitter, it deletes all of the children appropriately.  I'll take a look at having ownership on QML side, it might simplify things - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still interested in this problem, in Qt 5 (and so Qt 6), you can also use a custom [QQmlContext](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#details) with `QQmlContext::setContextProperty()` to setup external property (`orientation` in your case):

```cpp
QQmlEngine engine;

QQmlContext *context = new QQmlContext(engine.rootContext());
context->setContextProperty("myCustomOrientation", QVariant::fromValue(orientation));

// you can use a 'myCustomOrientation' property inside Sy_splitView.qml, e.g.
// `orientation: myCustomOrientation`
QQmlComponent splitComp(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/qml/Sy_splitView.qml"));
QObject* splitter = splitComp.create(context);
```

This should allow you to not fiddle with `beginCreate` and `completeCreate`.

Update:

There is also [QQmlComponent::createWithInitialProperties()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlcomponent.html#createWithInitialProperties) (from 5.14 onwards) that allows you to create an object and initialize its properties before the creation process finishes.

(And then [QQmlApplicationEngine::setInitialProperties()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlapplicationengine.html#setInitialProperties) is the application engine's version of the same functionality)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use a custom `QQmlIncubator` and the `QQmlComponent::create(QQmlIncubator & incubator, QQmlContext * context = 0, QQmlContext * forContext = 0)` factory method.

In particular, quoting from [the `QQmlIncubator` documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qqmlincubator.html):

> void QQmlIncubator::setInitialState(QObject * object) [virtual protected]
>
> Called after the object is first created, but before property bindings are evaluated and, if applicable, QQmlParserStatus::componentComplete() is called. This is equivalent to the point between QQmlComponent::beginCreate() and QQmlComponent::endCreate(), and can be used to assign initial values to the object's properties.
>
> The default implementation does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar situation for my own QML component. Just wanted to init some props before running some bindings. In pure QML I did it that way:

```
var some = component.createObject(this, {'modelClass': my_model});
```

From C++ I tried that way:

```
// create ui object
auto uiObject = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(component.beginCreate(ctx));
// place on ui
uiObject->setParentItem(cont);

// set model properties
classInstance->setView(QVariant::fromValue(uiObject));
classInstance->setPosition(QPointF(x, y));

// set ui object properties
uiObject->setProperty("modelClass", QVariant::fromValue(classInstance.get()));

// finish
component.completeCreate();
```

but I had binding errors because modelClass remains null! After digging for a while I found the cause. And it looks reasonable for me. I've changed my QML class!

```
Item {
    id: root
    // property var modelClass: null
    property var modelClass // just remove : null!
}
```

Properties with initial values right after invoking beginCreate are not visible from C++, until I call completeCreate(). But if I remove initial value property becomes visible and I can initialize it in C++ code