# How does one change the model property of a TableView in qml from c++

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qqmlapplicationengine

I am relatively new to QT, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am working on a Qt Quick Application, making use of the QQmlApplicationEngine for the UI. I made a subclass of QAbstractTableModel and implemented the necessary functions and successfully created and displayed a (singular) table on the Window.

Currently, how I linked the model in the QML file is by setting the *context property* of the *root property* of QQmlApplicationEngine.

***main.cpp***

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "tablecontroller.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  QSharedPointer<QQmlApplicationEngine> engine = 
                     QSharedPointer<QQmlApplicationEngine>::create();

  TableController theController(engine.toWeakRef());

  engine.data()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("TableController", &theController);

  engine.data()->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
  return app.exec();
}
```

***tabcontroller.h***

```
#ifndef TABLECONTROLLER_H
#define TABLECONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QWeakPointer>
#include <QHash>
#include <QList>

#include "tablemodel.h"

class TableController : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TableController(QWeakPointer<QQmlApplicationEngine> Engine, QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE void AddEntry();

signals:

public slots:

private:
  TE::TDT::TableModel m_TableModel;
  QList<QString> m_Headings;
};

#endif // TABLECONTROLLER_H
```

***tabcontroller.cpp***

```
#include "tablecontroller.h"
#include <QQmlContext>

TableController::TableController(QWeakPointer<QQmlApplicationEngine> Engine, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  m_Headings << "Heading1" << "Heading2" << "Heading3" << "Heading4";
  m_TableModel.setColumnHeadings(m_Headings);

  Engine.data()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", &m_TableModel);
}

void TableController::AddEntry()
{
  QHash<QString, QVariant> tempHash;
  int counter = 1;
  for (auto x : m_Headings)
  {
    tempHash.insert(x, QString::number(counter));
    counter++;
  }
  m_TableModel.addElement(tempHash);
}
```

***tablemodel.h***

```
#ifndef TABLEMODEL_H
#define TABLEMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QList>
#include <QString>
#include <QHash>

namespace TE {

namespace TDT {

class TableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QStringList userRoleNames READ userRoleNames CONSTANT)
public:
    explicit TableModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    enum MyModelRoles {
        UserRole1 = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        UserRole2,
    };

  void setFirstColumn(const QList<QString> &FirstColumn);

  void setColumnHeadings(const QList<QString> &ColumnHeadings);

  void addElement(const QHash<QString, QVariant> Entry);

  QStringList userRoleNames();

signals:

public slots:

// QAbstractTableModel interface
public:
  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
  int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
  QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const override;
  QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

private:
  QList<QHash<QString, QVariant>> m_TableData;
  QList<QString> m_ColumnHeadings;
  QMap<int, QString> m_roleNames;

};

}// TDT

}// TE

#endif // TABLEMODEL_H
```

***tablemodel.cpp***

```
#include "tablemodel.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractListModel>

TE::TDT::TableModel::TableModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{

}

int TE::TDT::TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
  Q_UNUSED(parent);
  return m_TableData.count();
}

int TE::TDT::TableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
  Q_UNUSED(parent);
  return m_ColumnHeadings.count();
}

QVariant TE::TDT::TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
  QVariant retVal;
  try {
     if(!index.isValid())
     {
         throw QString("Invalid index for inherited data function");
     }
     // Check row index
     if(index.row() >= m_TableData.count() || index.row() < 0)
     {
         throw QString("Index (row) out of bounds for data function");
     }
     //Check column index
     if(index.column() >= m_ColumnHeadings.count() || index.column() < 0)
     {
         throw QString("Index (column) out of bounds for data function");
     }

     QList<int> keys = m_roleNames.keys();

     if(role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole)
     {
         QString colKey = m_ColumnHeadings.at(index.column());
         if (m_TableData.at(index.row()).value(colKey).isNull())
         {
             retVal = QVariant();
         } else {
             retVal = m_TableData.at(index.row()).value(colKey);
         }
     } else if (m_roleNames.keys().contains(role)) {
         QHash<QString, QVariant> temp1 = m_TableData.at(index.row());
         retVal = m_TableData.at(index.row()).value(m_roleNames.value(role));
     }
     return retVal;

  } catch (QString &e) {
     qDebug() << e;
     return QVariant();
  }
}

QVariant TE::TDT::TableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
  Q_UNUSED(orientation);
  QVariant retVal;
  if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
  {
     retVal = m_ColumnHeadings.at(section);
  }
  return retVal;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> TE::TDT::TableModel::roleNames() const {
  // Populate the roles - basically the column headings
  QHash<int, QByteArray> roles = QAbstractTableModel::roleNames();

  // Should not overwrite existing roles
  int LastIndexOfUserRole = Qt::UserRole;
  for (int x = 1; x <= m_ColumnHeadings.count(); x++)
  {
     roles[LastIndexOfUserRole + x] = m_ColumnHeadings.at(x-1).toUtf8();
  }
  return roles;
}

QStringList TE::TDT::TableModel::userRoleNames() // Return ordered List of user-defined roles
{
  QHashIterator<int, QByteArray> i(roleNames());
  while (i.hasNext())
  {
     i.next();
     if(i.key() > Qt::UserRole)
     {
         m_roleNames[i.key()] = i.value();
     }
  }
  return m_roleNames.values();
}

void TE::TDT::TableModel::setColumnHeadings(const QList<QString> &ColumnHeadings)
{
  m_ColumnHeadings = ColumnHeadings;
}

void TE::TDT::TableModel::addElement(const QHash<QString, QVariant> Entry)
{
   beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), this->rowCount(QModelIndex()), this->rowCount(QModelIndex()));
   m_TableData.append(Entry);
   endInsertRows();
}
```

***main.qml***
    import QtQuick 2.5
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    id: mainwindow

    // template component for the column headings
    Component
    {
        id: columnComponent
        TableViewColumn{width: 100 }
    }

    TableView {
        id: tableview
        height: mainwindow.height - 50
        width: mainwindow.width
        y: 5
        x: 0
        visible: true
        resources:
        {
            var roleList = myModel.userRoleNames
            var temp = []
            for(var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++)
            {
                var role  = roleList[i]
                temp.push(columnComponent.createObject(tableview, { "role": role, "title": role}))
            }
            return temp
        }
        model: myModel
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: abutton
        anchors.top: tableview.bottom
        height: 40
        width: mainwindow.width

        Text {
            text: "Click to Add"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                TableController.AddEntry()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code adapted from:
[QML TableView with dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230818/qml-tableview-with-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Now, my question is, if I wanted to re-use the TableView as that defined in the ***main.qml*** I want to use another *model* for it. The problem is (from my limited understanding) that the "variable" that the model in the QML links to is static (defined at start-up), in this case, "myModel".

How can I change the model once I create another *instance* of this TableView? Will I have to link another "variable" every time?

I have tried to cast the TableView (in QML) to a QQuickItem (in c++) and trying to set the property there, to no avail (gives a null, but also QQuickItem doesn't have a "setModel" function)

Sorry for the long post, wanted to give as much information as possible.

Comment: You can expose your model to QML with [qmlRegisterType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html) and so create several model items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35755172/7094339

This guy saved my life :D
So it appears I needed to use the component.beginCreate() function.

Answer (score 0):

As @folibis said, one option is to make your model instantiable from QML, i.e. so that you can craete instances of the model in QML.

You can then add a method to the `TableController` to "register" these instances in case the controller needs to be aware of them.

Alternatively you still create the models inside `TableController` and make them accessible, e.g. via one property for each model, a list property or a `Q_INVOKABLE` method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to reuse your custom `TableView` with another model, you don't really need to change the `model` of your existing `TableView`.

For that you can define a new component in a separate file and use it elsewhere (some doc here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html)

In your case it could look like that :

`DynamicTableView.qml` :

```
TableView {
    //it's better not to set positioning properties in a component definition file.
    Component {
        id: columnComponent
        TableViewColumn { width: 100 }
    }  
    resources:
    {
        var roleList = model.userRoleNames // here you expect all your models to be an instance of your TableModel
        var temp = []
        for(var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++)
        {
            var role  = roleList[i]
            temp.push(columnComponent.createObject(tableview, { "role": role, "title": role}))
        }
        return temp
    }
}
```

You could then reuse your component in `main.qml` and define its `model` property :

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    id: mainwindow    

    DynamicTableView {
        id: tableview
        height: mainwindow.height - 50
        width: mainwindow.width
        y: 5
        x: 0
        model: myModel
    }    

    Rectangle {
        id: abutton
        anchors.top: tableview.bottom
        height: 40
        width: mainwindow.width    

        Text {
            text: "Click to Add"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }    

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                TableController.AddEntry()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still do not see how this solves my problem. I want to create multiple instances of the TableView, all having their own **unique** models, defined by the QAbstractTableModel sub-class defined in the c++ code. How do I set the model for each instance? Say if I wanted to create 2 (or any arbitrary number of) tables in one "tab", that would mean instantiating the TableView twice (or more), how will I set the models then?

Comment: Like that ? `DynamicTableView { id: firstTableview; model: myModel1; ... } DynamicTableView { id: secondTableview; model: myModel2; ... }`

Comment: But that requires me to hard code the models... As the title of the question says, how does one do it form c++? The application that I am writing lets the user insert a Table (or tables), and the user will be able to choose what parameters he wants to be in the table (hence the dynamic setting of the model). Sorry if I did not explain this properly in the question. EDIT: I am also trying to maintain the MVC architecture, I don't want to do too much QML modifying from the c++, in this case, I want to minimise "inserting" code into the QML file, I merely want to "set" the model.

Comment: The simplest way is to instantiate the model in QML, like suggested by @folibis and myself.
Or, also as suggested before, you have a list of models and create one view for each list entry

Comment: @GrecKo instead of the script code for `resources` you could likely also use an `Instantiator`. Should theoretically even allow dynamic column changes at runtime

Comment: @KevinKrammer I just copied OP's code for `resources`, I also thought of using an `Instantiator` but you there's no `addColumn` function in `TablewView`, so it cannot really be done.

Comment: But yeah you should expose a list of model from c++ and instantiates a `TableView` for each with a `Repeater` or `ListView`. I don't think you should instantiate a model from QML unless you want to handle your business logic in QML, I prefer to do that in c++

Comment: On my offline doc, there's is no `addColumn` function for `TableView`, but it's documented in the online one : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#addColumn-method

Comment: @GrecKo there is also insertColumn which even takes the index into account and removeColumn for the `Instantiator`'s onObjectRemoved. But yet, I see now that this was part of the question's code :)